# ViewState does not keep variables and errors out

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, viewstate

Let me see if I can re-word this better and maybe get some more relavent answers or ideas.  This has happened a few times now as reported by users.  I cannot reproduce on my local server.  I am checking each of the IIS settings now to make sure they match.

But on our production server here are the details:

Single Server

No Authentication

IIS7

ASP.Net 3.5

Totally Random when it happens

Using ViewState

Any Ideas?  The actual error from the event log!

---

My event log has the following errors:

Event code: 4005

Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired.

Event time: 14/03/2008 13:19:26

Event time (UTC): 14/03/2008 13:19:26

Event ID: d9f0333c2eed46e0b0207da69d2ea70e

Event sequence: 154

Event occurrence: 5

Event detail code: 50202

Comment: Why would you vote and put no answer???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the accepted solution at:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_21968000.html

If the authentication ticket expires you could have that error.

Comment: Hi, I think you were down voted because people here don't like that site you recommended. :-) Also, try to add a snippet of the answer in the body of the text of your reply, in case the link goes down.